# Monitoring a device's download/upload usage on linksys router?

Tags: router, logging, linksys, upload

I have multiple computers and 2 PS3's all using the same linksys router(one wireless). Is there a way to log how much each device downloads/uploads for a give period of time?

We still have download limits here in Belgium so I'm trying to see what really hogs up most of my connection out of all of these ...

I have a WRT54GS model.

Answer (score 1):

If the default Linksys firmware on your router doesn't have the features you need, you might want to look at [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/), or another open-source replacement firmware. These can enhance your router with many feature you don't get off-the-shelf. Check out [BWlog](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/BWlog) for DD-WRT, not sure if it monitors per-host, but it might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, all the 3rd-party firmwares for the WRT54GS model such as [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com) and Tomato will only monitor bandwidth for all ports combined.  You can possibly monitor each individual IPs with the Tomato or DD-WRT firmware via command-line by modifying the IP Tables with a counter and use a computer to collect the information via SNMP from your router.  You can use Gargoyle Router firmware which will monitor each port separately; however, the firmware is only for WRT54GL model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is possible on the WRT54GS model using native firmware.  I would investigate upgrading your firmware using http://dd-wrt.com to do this monitoring.

The other possible solution is to turn on the router's quality of service options to prioritize the content you desire. That way the PS3's can do their thing and just be scaled back only when something more important needs to be done.